# Проблема с кодировкой grep лога с удаленной машины и сохранение вывода stdout в файл

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Сохраняются логи без форматирования с кучей спец символов перехода строки и т.д. Плюс лог пишется в UTF8 а когда мы его тянем из буфера удаленной машины на нашу локальную тачку он заливается в нечитаемом виде. Как обойти проблему с кодировкой? Ктонибуь может помочь? На каждом сервере по 10+ машин в которых пишутся логи. Создаем списки серверов. По очереди обходим каждую машину создаем список логов и выполняем греп лога (например по дате). После сохраняем вывод в отдельный файл с именем машины с которой грепали лог.

```
import paramiko
import select
import re


lst=['192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2','192.168.0.3']
com = 'ls /home/servers/logs/ | grep Application'


def SSH(server_address):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=server_address,
                username='user',
                password='pass',
                port=22)
    return ssh

def run_commands_remote(command, server_address):
    session = SSH(server_address).get_transport().open_session()
    session.set_combine_stderr(True)
    session.get_pty()
    session.exec_command(command)
    stdin = session.makefile('wb', -1)
    stdout = session.makefile('rb', -1)
    return (stdout.read().decode())

#Функция греп лога
def do_grep(log_file, grep_pattern, server_address ):
    remote_command = 'grep --line-buffered "%s" %s ' % (grep_pattern, log_file)
    print (remote_command)
    ssh = SSH(server_address)
    transport = ssh.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    channel.exec_command(remote_command)

    while 1:
        try:
                buffer_string = channel.recv(256)
                File_log(str(log)+'.log', buffer_string)
                done = False
                while not done:
                    more = channel.recv(256)
                    if not more:
                        done = True
                    else: 
                        File_log(str(log)+'.log', more)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            print ('got ctrl+c')
            break

ssh.close()
print ('client closed')

#Удаляем пустые элементы в списке   
def clear(l):
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            clear(e)
        if isinstance(e, str) and len(e) == 0:
            l.remove(e)

#Пишем в файл для создания списка
def files(file, out):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(out))
        f.close()
        f = open(file, 'r')
        f.seek(0)
        l = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        l=[spisok.rstrip("\n") for spisok in l]
        clear(l)
        return(l)

#Создаем файл с отфильтрованным логом.
def File_log(file_name, log):
with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(log)+"\n")
    f.close()   

for i in lst:
    servers = run_commands_remote(com, server_address=i)
    ls = files('servers.txt', servers)
    for log in ls:
        out1 = 'ls -lohtr /home/servers/logs/'+str(log)
        output = run_commands_remote(out1, server_address=i)
        ls2 = files('log.txt', output)
        pattern = 'Mar 02'
        out2 = '/home/servers/logs/'+str(log)+'/'+str(ls2)
        do_grep(out2,pattern,i)
```

Comment: код типа: `with open(file, 'w') as f: ... f.close()` намекает, что вам следует разбить задачу на более мелкие шаги и тестировать их отдельно. Оттестировав по отдельности, имея большую уверенность и понимание, что код делает, можно пытаться интегрировать отдельные шаги в более крупные блоки и тестировать их.

Comment: Конечно такое решение имеет право на существование, но почему не упростить себе жизнь, сливая логи с серверов на один хост (syslog) и грепать все что надо на этом хосте?

Comment: Архитектура проекта сложилась до меня) И это не большой кластер серверов. Если получится собирать логи с этого кластера будут более заковыристые задачки.